# Problem referencing .Web project in Silverlight project

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, ria, domainservices

I'm trying to reference my domain service by following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707363%28v=VS.91%29.aspx) documentation.

The following two declarations work fine

```
xmlns:riaControls = "clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls; 
   assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DomainServices"
```

and

```
xmlns:data = "clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;
   assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
```

but I'm having problems with this one

```
xmlns:domain="clr-namespace:SNMPApplication.Web"
```

This error appears, even after I rebuild the whole solution:

> Undefined CLR namespace. The
>   'clr-namespace' URI refers to a
>   namespace that is not included in the
>   assembly.

I've tried adding a reference to my Silverlight project but I get this error

> You can only add project references to
>   other Silverlight projects in the
>   solution.

Does anyone have an ideia of what the problem is? :/

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The way you add a reference to a RIA DomainService is not through the traditional Add Reference dialog.  You do it through the project settings.  In the Silverlight Application, goto the project settings, specifically the 'Silverlight' tab.  On that tab will be a 'WCF RIA Services link'.  You'll be able to select your project that contains the DomainService.

After you select the project, Visual Studio will generate code for your Silverlight application.  This is found in a Generated_Code folder (which isn't visible in the project, though you can see it in the folder).  This is where your code that you need to reference will be.

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually creating a reference to your web project when you do this, it resolves it at compiletime to create the generated g.cs files (I suspect), This is one of those magic things that does stuff in the background ( I think it stores it in your project file and you set it in the project properties --> silverlight tab under WCF Ria Services link).

Please check the following:

Your SNMPApplication.Web is in the same solution as your Silverlight project (SNMPApplication)
and that your reference is the same as your DomainService class namespace you added to your web.Project class (It might be in a sub folder and that is why it's not working,

If you haven't created a domain service please add one as this is what silverlight and ria services uses to connect between your entity model and silverlight. (Have a look [here](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Creating-applications-with-.NET-RIA-Service-Part-3-Adding-DomainService-class.aspx) from Adding a DomainService class

xmlns:domain="clr-namespace:SNMPApplication.Web"

Answer (score 0):

If you genuinely need to access the Web project from your SNMPApplication project, then I think what you'll need is either of the answers to this question: [How to access web application class into silverlight application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735453/how-to-access-web-application-class-into-silverlight-application)

Comment: I added the domain service as as link but now I'm getting assembly errors about the Entity Framework :/ I'm not sure if this is the correct approach.

Comment: It's not.  See the other two answers.  ;]